# Issue while trying to create a fall detection algorithm (Android)

Tags: android, algorithm, accelerometer

I am currently trying to write a fall detection algorithm on android. I have successfully detected free fall, however when the phone lands the resulting vector is always around 1G and I am not able to create an upper threshold. Here is my code for the method:

```
if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
    float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
    double totalAccel = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) + Math.pow(z,2));

    if(totalAccel < FALL_THRESHOLD && !isFalling){
       isFalling = true;
    }

    if(isFalling && totalAccel > FALL_THRESHOLD){
        isFalling = false;
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.values);
        view.setText("" + totalAccel);
    }
```

Comment: what is your FALL_THRESHOLD  value?
i am trying with the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518729/android-fall-detection
but can not success