# Android Fall detection

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am implementing the fall detection using accelerometer sensor, and create below code.

```
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent foEvent) {


        if (foEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            double loX = foEvent.values[0];
            double loY = foEvent.values[1];
            double loZ = foEvent.values[2];

            double loAccelerationReader = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(loX, 2)
                    + Math.pow(loY, 2)
                    + Math.pow(loZ, 2));
            mlPreviousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i(TAG, "loX : " + loX + " loY : " + loY + " loZ : " + loZ);
            if (loAccelerationReader <= 6.0) {
                moIsMin = true;
                Log.i(TAG, "min");
            }

            if (moIsMin) {
                i++;
                Log.i(TAG, " loAcceleration : " + loAccelerationReader);
                if (loAccelerationReader >= 30) {
                    long llCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long llTimeDiff = llCurrentTime - mlPreviousTime;
                    Log.i(TAG, "loTime :" + llTimeDiff);
                    if (llTimeDiff >= 10) {
                        moIsMax = true;
                        Log.i(TAG, "max");
                    }
                }

            }

            if (moIsMin && moIsMax) {
                Log.i(TAG, "loX : " + loX + " loY : " + loY + " loZ : " + loZ);
                Log.i(TAG, "FALL DETECTED!!!!!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "FALL DETECTED!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i = 0;
                moIsMin = false;
                moIsMax = false;
            }

            if (i > 5) {
                i = 0;
                moIsMin = false;
                moIsMax = false;
            }
        }        
}
```

its give me fall detected, but if i am riding or running it will also give me fall alert.

if i throw device from 6 inch, alert shown.

I also see the sensitivity is device specific.

when i test moto e and mi 4 with same height

Moto e return maximum 32 value for `loAccelerationReader`

and in mi 4 it will return 60 value for `loAccelerationReader`

can any one help me out for the correct way.

Comment: This code is not working with my Huawie Watch. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got some solution not sure its work for all or not, but i am using below code and its working for me.

```
if (foEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        double loX = foEvent.values[0];
        double loY = foEvent.values[1];
        double loZ = foEvent.values[2];

        double loAccelerationReader = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(loX, 2)
                + Math.pow(loY, 2)
                + Math.pow(loZ, 2));

        DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double ldAccRound = Double.parseDouble(precision.format(loAccelerationReader));

        if (ldAccRound > 0.3d && ldAccRound < 0.5d) {
           //Do your stuff
        }
   }
```

Comment: How to find Free fall duration when a free fall ends

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the above calculations in the code?

Comment: @RaRa ldAccRound > 0.3d && ldAccRound < 0.5d where does this value come from?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. It can detect fall!  But it also detect other non-fall events. My suggestion is instead of single point thresholding (e.g. magnitude > 30), get a time interval of accelerometer readings (e.g. 1 second). I am sure that that the readings for fall, running, and driving will be very different statistically (e.g. mean, variance). I hope this can serve as a starting point for your next iteration of detection algorithm.

It is very likely that the readings will be different from machine to machine since the accelerometers they use are different and may have different sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks buddy for reply, i added a long time but it will cant deliver accurate result, some time its value more then 50 even drop from the 6 inch. and some time different will 15 when drop from the 3 feet. so my concern is how will i check interval. i also used foEvent.timestamp, but it didn't work

Comment: Indeed, different devices will throw different values (you can't even be sure about the interval or readings!). The only way I can think to workaround this is to add some kind of calibration that will have to be done by the user